# Graphql Connect Error - Only getting Query or Subscription or both

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, hasura

We are encountering an error in the setup of our application to the graphql connection. Our main need is Subscriptions, currently our code handles these fine.  But our queries respond with "Leads not found in query_root"

When we modify the positioning of our connection code, the query now will work but subscriptions stop connecting.

```
const scheme = proto => {
    return window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? `${proto}s` : proto;
};

const wsurl = `${scheme('ws')}://${HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENGINE_HOSTNAME}/v1/graphql`;
const httpurl = `${scheme('http')}://${HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENGINE_HOSTNAME}/v1/graphql`;

// Create a WebSocket link:
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: wsurl,
    options: {
        reconnect: true,
        connectionParams: {
            headers: {
                'x-hasura-access-key': `${HASURA_ACCESS_KEY}`
            }
        }
    }
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: httpurl,
    options: {
        connectionParams: {
            headers: {
                'x-hasura-access-key': `${HASURA_ACCESS_KEY}`
            }
        }
    }
});

const link = split(
    // split based on operation type
    ({ query }) => {
        const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
        return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default client;
```

In the link const, if we put wsLink below httpLink then wsLink stops and httpLink works.

Comment: You can technically use a single websocket link to make queries, mutations and subscriptions. Here's an example - https://github.com/hasura/learn-graphql/blob/master/tutorials/frontend/react-apollo-hooks/app-final/src/components/App.js

Comment: I tried commenting out the httpLink, now when trigger the query the page is blank with no errors.  But subscriptions are still working!